# Why does two surfaces have the same extrinsic topology?

Tags: general-topology

I was recently reading 'The shape of space'. And this question is in the book.

[The shape of space pic 3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SGv.png)

It says that (c) and (f) haves the same extrinsic topology. But I can't understand why. In (c), two rings can be separated from each other. But in (f), two rings cannot be separated from each other. Why do s two have the same extrinsic topology? Is there something I misunderstood? I found the same question here, but I still can't understand.

Comment: Where did you find the same question?

Comment: @NDewolf https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661720/why-do-these-two-surfaces-have-the-same-extrinsic-topology

Comment: I don't think one can say more than @user856 in the comments of that question. By contracting the tube connecting the bases of the loops in (f) one gets a sphere-like body as in (c).

Comment: Ah, I found the way to make (f) as (a). Got it.